# Creating an element by using .append() and assigning onclick handler directly afterwards

Tags: jquery, html

Is it ok to directly assign an onclick-handler to an element that was inserted into the html code just before by using .append()/.after() or can it be that this element is not "ready" yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is totally OK to *assign* event listener to an element (or an element's child-element), and then insert that element into DOM.

As the question is about jquery. Here is an jquery example:

```js
var buttonWrapper = $('<div>mmmmmmmm<button class="btn">click</button></div>');
var button = buttonWrapper.find('button.btn');
button.on('click', clickListener);
var container = $('#container');

function clickListener() {
  alert('clicked!');
}

container.append(buttonWrapper);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
content
</div>
```

Comment: Inside my element there are several child elements and I cannot access them when I am defining an element like `var = $('<div id="parent"><div id="child1"></div><div id="child2"></div></div>');`

Comment: Actually, you can access the child elements. I've edited my answer to include this scenario.

Comment: This really helped me and solved my problem, but I think I gonna use `.children()` as it only looks for children 1 level below the selected element which is sufficient in my case. Thank you!

Comment: you are welcome :) And I think you made a correct decision: if `.children()` works well, don't use `.find()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the onClick tag as an html onClick attribute. This will ensure that it is ready.

`something.append('<htmlelement something="" onClick="functionToTrigger(parameters)">ValueMaybe</htmlelement>');`

> Using Dom Elements would definitely slow down your webpage.